# Sequelize: Optional limit parameter

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've seen a few questions on optional where clauses and order params, both of which I can implement, but I was wondering how to have an optional `limit` parameter? Maybe I'm missing something easy, but I can't see anything obvious in the docs

If I specify it like this:

```
const limit = req.query.limit;
Example.findAll({ 
  limit: limit
})
```

how can I omit `limit` in certain situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define `findAll` options outside `findAll` call and add `limit` prop optionally only if you have a value in `req.query.limit`:

```js
const options = {
}
if (req.query.limit) {
  options.limit = req.query.limit
}
Example.findAll(options)
```

Or you can try to pass `null` if you don't ave a value in the `req.query.limit` (should work in PostgreSQL for instance).